# spark convert a column of a dataframe from name to id according a hive table mapping name and id

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, rdd

First ,we have a hive table category in hive:

```
id  |   name
1   |   history
2   |   art
```

...

Then we read a book collection from mongodb to spark dataframes:

```
bookname    |      category
Europe      |      history book
Drawing     |      arts
```

here,if book.category contains category.name then I need to convert it to id.
for example,the output I expected is a dataframe like this:

```
bookname    |      category
Europe      |      1
Drawing     |      2
```

Caution!I know I can use rdd.map() but the problem is the number of the fields is bigger the 22 in fact,but tuple23 is not allowed,so I can`t use rdd.map like this:

```
bookDf.rdd.map(f=>{
   ....
   (field1,field2,.....filed50)//illegle
}).toDF()
```

any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done with specific join:

```
val categoriesDF = List(
  (1, "history"),
  (2, "art")).toDF("id", "name")
val booksDF = List(
  ("Europe", "history book"),
  ("Drawing", "arts")).toDF("bookname", "category")

val joinCondition = $"category".contains($"name")
val result = booksDF.join(categoriesDF, joinCondition)

result.select("bookname","id").show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------+---+
|bookname|id |
+--------+---+
|Europe  |1  |
|Drawing |2  |
+--------+---+
```